# Solve a geometry problem by using vectors.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

In triangle $ABC$, the bisector of angle $A$ meets side $BC$ in point $D $ and the bisector of
angle $B$ meets side $AC$ in point $E$. Given that $DE$ is parallel to $AB$, show that $AE = BD$
and that the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles.

---

The solution of this problem is completely based on pure geometry. Using alternate angles and basic proportionality theorem. I however want to solve the problem using vectors. We know $$\vec {AB}=\lambda \vec {ED} $$ 
also $$\widehat{BE}=\widehat{BD}+\widehat{DA} $$ $$\widehat{AD}=\widehat{AE}+\widehat{AB} $$
I am stuck here.

Comment: Angle bisectors are awkward using vectors.

Comment: What are the second and third equations? Do the hats mean unit vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overrightarrow{AB}=\underline{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}=\underline{b}$

Then $$\overrightarrow{AD}=\lambda\left(\frac{\underline{a}}{|a|}+\frac{\underline{b}}{|b|}\right)$$

And likewise, $$\overrightarrow{BE}=\mu\left(-\frac{\underline{a}}{|a|}+\frac{\underline{b}-\underline{a}}{|\underline{b}-\underline{a}|}\right)$$

Also let $\overrightarrow{BD}=p(\underline{b}-\underline{a})$ and $\overrightarrow{AE}=q\underline{b}$

Then $$\overrightarrow{AD}=\underline{a}+p(\underline{b}-\underline{a})=\lambda\left(\frac{\underline{a}}{|a|}+\frac{\underline{b}}{|b|}\right)$$

It therefore follows that $p=\frac{\lambda}{|b|}$ and $1-p=\frac{\lambda}{|a|}$

Therefore solving these gives $$p=\frac{|a|}{|a|+|b|}$$

Following the same routine, we also find that $$q=\frac{|a|}{|\underline{b}-\underline{a}|+|a|}$$

Then $$\overrightarrow{DE}==\frac{|a|\underline{b}}{|\underline{b}-\underline{a}|+|a|}-\underline{a}-\frac{|a|(\underline{b}-\underline{a})}{|a|+|b|}$$

This vector is parallel to $\underline{a}$ so it follows that $$\frac{|a|}{|\underline{b}-\underline{a}|+|a|}=\frac{|a|}{|a|+|b|}$$

Thus it follows that $|\underline{b}-\underline{a}|=|b|$ and the triangle is isosceles. We can also deduce that $|AE|=|BD|$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for **DE** || **AB** and **AD** as transversal, alternate angles **ADE** and **DAB** are equal. And **AD** being the bisector of angle **BAC**, angles **DAB** and **DAC** are equal. So we have angles **DAC** and **ADE** equal and in triangle **ADE**, we have angles **DAE** and **ADE** equal. So we can say that **DE**=**AE**.

Similarly, we again observe that for **DE** || **AB** and **BE** as transversal, alternate angles **BED** and **EBA** are equal. And **BE** being the bisector of angle **ABC**, angles **EBA** and **EBC** are equal. So we have angles **BED** and **EBC** equal and in triangle **ADE**, we have angles **BED** and **EBD** equal. So we can say that **DE**=**BD**.

Comparing above results, we conclude that **AE**=**BD**.

Can you use this result and prove the second case? It is easy. Try it.

Comment: I specially want to solve the problem using vectors.